# Realtime formatting of cucumber output for 'Scenario Outline' with example table

Tags: ruby, formatting, cucumber

I am using cucumber and slowhandcuke gem. I see that it doesn't format scenario's outline with an example table even if I use string from slowhandcuke repo:

```
cucumber --format 'Slowhandcuke::Formatter'
```

Standard  cucumber's `--format pretty` also doesn't take any effect. Do you have any ideas that may be the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
cucmber -x
```

According to the man page:

> -x, --expand                     Expand Scenario Outline Tables in output.